# Disable auto expand of textarea and page on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Am creating message chat template using HTML and CSS Bootstrap, everything looks good but when I open the chat in mobile and click on text area to type message the interface expand in that case user have to scroll to see the send button again and the chat box also will not fit the screen as I wanted it to. I set the width to 100% max-width 100%. How do I make the text area not to expand the page and also disable the user from expanding the page in mobile using CSS or jQuery?

**Code Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  max = $(document).height() - $('#qnimater').offset().top;
  $('#qnimate').css('max-height',max);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var height = $(document).height();
  height = height - (100);
  $("#qnimater").css({ 'max-height' : height.toString() });
});
```

```css
 @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300);
 @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
 body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
 .popup-box {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }
 .round.hollow {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
 }
 .round.hollow a {
  border: 2px solid #ff6701;
  border-radius: 35px;
  color: red;
  color: #ff6701;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding: 10px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }
 .round.hollow a:hover {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 35px;
  color: red;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding: 10px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 .popup-box-on {
  display: block !important;
 }
 .popup-box .popup-head {
  background-color: #fff;
  clear: both;
  color: #7b7b7b;
  display: inline-table;
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Oswald;
 }
 .bg_none i {
  border: 1px solid #ff6701;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #ff6701;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 33px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 33px;
 }
 .bg_none:hover i {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 33px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 33px;
 }
 .bg_none {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
 }
 .popup-box .popup-head .popup-head-right {
  margin: 11px 7px 0;
 }
 .popup-box .popup-messages {} 
 .popup-head-left img {
  border: 1px solid #7b7b7b;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 44px;
 }
 .popup-messages-footer > textarea {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b2b2b2 !important;
  height: 34px !important;
  margin: 7px;
  padding: 5px !important;
  border: medium none;
  width: 85% !important;
 }
 .popup-messages-footer {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .popup-messages-footer .btn-footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2px 5px 10px 6px;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .simple_round {
  background: #d1d1d1 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #4b4b4b !important;
  height: 21px;
  padding: 0 0 0 1px;
  width: 21px;
 }
 .popup-box .popup-messages {
  background: #3f9684 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
 }
 .direct-chat-messages {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
 }
 .popup-messages .chat-box-single-line {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a4c6b5;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 7px 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .popup-messages abbr.timestamp {
  background: #3f9684 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 11px;
 }
 .popup-head-right .btn-group {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  vertical-align: top !important;
 }
 .chat-header-button {
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #636364;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .popup-head-right .btn-group .dropdown-menu {
  border: medium none;
  min-width: 122px;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .popup-head-right .btn-group .dropdown-menu li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  color: #303030;
 }
 .popup-messages abbr.timestamp {
  background: #3f9684 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 11px;
 }
 .popup-messages .chat-box-single-line {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a4c6b5;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 7px 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .popup-messages .direct-chat-messages {
  height: auto;
 }
 .popup-messages .direct-chat-text {
  background: #dfece7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #dfece7;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #1f2121;
 }
 .popup-messages .direct-chat-timestamp {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.6;
 }
 .popup-messages .direct-chat-name {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0 0 0 49px !important;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.9;
 }
 .popup-messages .direct-chat-info {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
 }
 .popup-messages .big-round {
  margin: -9px 0 0 !important;
 }
 .popup-head-left{
     margin-top: 5px;
vertical-align: middle;
 }
 .popup-messages .direct-chat-img {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #3f9684 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  /*margin: -21px 0 0;*/
  width: 40px;
 }
 .direct-chat-reply-name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  opacity: 0.9;
 }
 
 .direct-chat-img-reply-small {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 8px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #3f9684;
 }
 .popup-messages .direct-chat-msg {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
 }


 .direct-chat-text::after,
 .direct-chat-text::before {
  border-color: transparent #dfece7 transparent transparent;
 }
 .direct-chat-text::after,
 .direct-chat-text::before {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  border-color: transparent #d2d6de transparent transparent;
  border-image: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: medium;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 15px;
  width: 0;
 }
 .direct-chat-text::after {
  border-width: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
 }
 .popup-messages .direct-chat-text {
  background: #dfece7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #dfece7;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #1f2121;
 }
 .direct-chat-text {
  background: #d2d6de none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #444;
  margin: 5px 0 0 50px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
 }
 .popup-messages-footer .uk-input-group-addon{
        height: 34px !important;
        padding: 0px;
        border: medium none;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
 }
.uk-input-group-addon .glyphicon.glyphicon-send {
    color: #3F9684;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 0 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="qnimate">
  <div class="popup-head">
   <div class="popup-head-left pull-left"><a href="#">Univercial Hotel Hall</a></div>
   <div class="popup-head-right pull-right text-center">
       <div class="btn-group">
       <button class="chat-header-button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> </button>
       </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
     <button class="chat-header-button" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></button>
     <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
      <li><a href="#">Media</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Block</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Clear Chat</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Email Chat</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
                
    <button data-widget="remove" id="removeClass" class="chat-header-button pull-right" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup-messages">




   <div class="direct-chat-messages">
                 
                 
                     <div class="chat-box-single-line"> <abbr class="timestamp">October 8th, 2015</abbr></div>
    <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
    <div class="direct-chat-msg doted-border me">
     <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
     <img alt="message user image" src="https://d2xngy2dw7hums.cloudfront.net/media/photos/profiles/2017/09/26/ujahchigozie_1506417938.jpg" class="direct-chat-img">
     <!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
     <div class="direct-chat-text">Hey bro, how’s everything going ? </div>
     <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span></div>
     <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
    
        <div class="chat-box-single-line"> <abbr class="timestamp">October 8th, 2015</abbr></div>
    <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
    <div class="direct-chat-msg doted-border me">
     <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
     <img alt="message user image" src="https://d2xngy2dw7hums.cloudfront.net/media/photos/profiles/2017/09/26/ujahchigozie_1506417938.jpg" class="direct-chat-img">
     <!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
     <div class="direct-chat-text">Hey bro, how’s everything going ? </div>
     <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span></div>
     <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
    
    
        <div class="chat-box-single-line"> <abbr class="timestamp">October 8th, 2015</abbr></div>
    <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
    <div class="direct-chat-msg doted-border me">
     <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
     <img alt="message user image" src="https://d2xngy2dw7hums.cloudfront.net/media/photos/profiles/2017/09/26/ujahchigozie_1506417938.jpg" class="direct-chat-img">
     <!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
     <div class="direct-chat-text">Hey bro, how’s everything going ? </div>
     <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span></div>
     <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
    
  
    <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
    <div class="direct-chat-msg doted-border me">
     <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
     <img alt="message user image" src="https://d2xngy2dw7hums.cloudfront.net/media/photos/profiles/2017/09/26/ujahchigozie_1506417938.jpg" class="direct-chat-img">
     <!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
     <div class="direct-chat-text">Hey bro, how’s everything going Hey bro, how’s everything going Hey bro, how’s everything going Hey bro, how’s everything going ? </div>
     <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span></div>
     <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
    

    <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
    <div class="direct-chat-msg doted-border me">
     <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
     <img alt="message user image" src="https://d2xngy2dw7hums.cloudfront.net/media/photos/profiles/2017/09/26/ujahchigozie_1506417938.jpg" class="direct-chat-img">
     <!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
     <div class="direct-chat-text">Hey bro, how’s everything going ? </div>
     <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span></div>
     <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->

            <br/><br/>
   </div>





  </div>
  <div class="popup-messages-footer">
   <textarea id="status_message" placeholder="Type a message..."
   rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea>
   <span class="uk-input-group-addon"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i></a></span>
   <div class="btn-footer col-xs-12">
    <button class="bg_none"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></button>
    <button class="bg_none"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i></button>
    <button class="bg_none"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i></button>
    <button class="bg_none pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i></button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

**This is how I want it to be**

[image]

**This what is display when typing**

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl0vG.jpg)

**After typing it looks like this**

[image]

Comment: can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: @ShadowFiend where do should i publish the code for your view? but here is a page to the chat example http://event2u.org/chat.html, please i also check the chat on my Samsung android and is working very well as i want it to, this problem is on on iphone

Comment: can't you post it here?

Comment: @ShadowFiend, is long lines of html and css i don't know the actual path to post here, that why i past you a link to the page. please here https://jsfiddle.net/75nj2prz/

Comment: Philip I have added your code to your question. But your code does not replicate your issue exactly. Please have a look.

Comment: @KiranDash, thanks for adding it, my question is how do i force the page to maintain max-width of 100% it don't was it to expand even when user try to expand the page width just like whatsapp